# Unable to execute commands inside docker container in Jenkins Execute Shell

Tags: linux, shell, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Docker container is successfully created using docker run command in Jenkins execute shell.
Now inside docker container i want to run few of the commands. But i noticed that the commands are not executing inside container.

```
echo password | sudo -S docker pull image

sudo docker images

imageid=`echo password | sudo -S docker images|grep imagename|tr -s ' '|cut -d' ' -f3`

sudo docker run -i --name=test $imageid /bin/bash

container=`echo password | sudo -S docker ps -all|grep test|cut -d' ' -f1`

#First check user if its inside the docker container
whoami

#above showed that its not inside the container as showed the machine user name instead of root user
#As a work around i tried to restart and execute the container

rest=`sudo docker restart $container`

out=`sudo docker exec -i $container /bin/bash`

whoami

# Above still not shows the root user and i am not able to execute the commands in side docker container on Jenkins
```

Comment: Use docker exec with the -i (interactive) flag to keep stdin open and -t to allocate a terminal: docker exec -i -t container_name /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your situation, but everytime i find myself with similar problems I try to execute the commands manually to debug the process. Use the following command to go inside the docker container:

```
docker exec -it <my_container> bash
```

Once inside the container that was created, execute the commands just as you are doing in the DockerFile. This will improve your debug process.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you trying to execute the docker commands like ex:  docker image inside the container so first of all check inside the container docker is installed if not then u not able to use docker commands inside container.

ex:
docker run -it ubuntu

after above command you will be inside container as below.

## root : docker images

so here inside the container docker images will not work as docker is not installed inside container.